# Strange behavior of printf and i++

Tags: c

I always forget which of `i++` and `++i` return which value. To test this I wrote the fallowing code:

```
int i;
i = 6;
printf ("i = %d, i++ = %d\n",i, i++);
printf ("i = %d, ++i = %d\n",i, ++i);
```

The resulting (unexpected and strange) output is:

```
i = 7, i++ = 6
i = 8, ++i = 8
```

But when I break down the `printf`s to 4 separate commands, I get the expected result:

```
printf ("i = %d, ",i);
printf ("i++ = %d\n",i++);
printf ("i = %d, ",i);
printf ("++i = %d\n",++i);
```

gives:

```
i = 6, i++ = 6
i = 7, ++i = 8
```

Why does this happens?

Comment: order of evaluation of parameters is unspecifyed

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question.

Comment: I don't think the duplicate applies here since the variable is only being modified once.

Comment: @Bathsheba: `i` is being modified *and read* without an intervening sequence point, which makes the behavior undefined. [C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.5/2: "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect
on the same scalar object *or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
object*, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Bathsheba: yes, that's only in the context of the comma acting as an operator; it does not introduce a sequence point when used to separate parameters in a function call.

Comment: I've added you comment to my answer and wiki'd it since your edit radically alters the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have both unspecified and undefined behaviour:

*Unspecified behaviour*: you don't know the order of evaluation of the parameters in the `printf` call. 
(The C standard does not specify this: it's up to the compiler and it's free to choose a way that best matches the machine architecture).

*Undefined behaviour*: The commas in the function call are *not* sequencing points. The behaviour is undefined as you're attempting to read and modify the same object without an intervening sequence point.

Answer (score -3):

Because in you first block `i` is `6` and `after` the `printf` statement it gets incremented because it's `postfix`!

After that in the `second` printf statement it's `prefix` and gets executed `before` it gets used so 7 + 1 = 8.

In your second code block `i` is `6` in the first `printf` statement, because it's `postfix`! That's why the second output is `7` and the last printf statement has a `prefix` increment so it gets incremented `before` it gets used and is `8`!

Prefix/ Postfix:

```
i++  //gets incremented AFTER it gets used (e.g. in a operation)
++i  //gets incremented BEFORE it gets used (e.g. in a operation)
```

**EDIT:**

The evaluation order of the arguments of a printf statement is unspecifyed !

Comment: It doesn't get incremented **after** the first print statement though. Going in `i=6` and the statement prints `i = 7, i++ = 6`. If it were not incremented until after this statement, the output would have been `i = 6, i++ = 6`

Comment: @Rizier123, the question isn't about what `i++` and `++i` do, but about the unexpected order in which they got executed inside the `printf`.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed yep! Sry first looked every time at the second argument of the printf statement and never saw the first one! edited my answer! (That's clear that this is unspecifyed)